# Error al colgar sitio MVC C# en el localhost como subsitio

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Solicito su ayuda, en mi PC de forma local en el IIS tengo un sitio, he creado un subsitio dirigido al proyecto Login, lo estoy tratando de visualizar de la siguiente forma:

http://localhost/Login/Aplicacion/ValidaAplicacion?id_aplicacion=2

**Me envía el siguiente error:**

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/Login'.
>   Error de configuración
>   Descripción: Error durante el procesamiento de un archivo de configuración requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error específicos siguientes y modifique el archivo de configuración en consecuencia.

Cabe resaltar que al correrlo desde Visual Studio, es funcional, pero la ruta de acceso es así:

http://localhost:63694/Aplicacion/ValidaAplicacion?id_aplicacion=2

Este es el `RouteConfig` que tengo

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Aplicacion", action = "ValidaAplicacion", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: Puedes poner el web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tu aplicación funcione en el nuevo Subdominio de IIS, debes añadir una **nueva ruta** al `RouteConfig` de la siguiente manera:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "Login/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Aplicacion", action = "ValidaAplicacion", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Aplicacion", action = "ValidaAplicacion", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Rafael por la aportación

He ingresado la modificación al RouteConfig, y al ejecutar desde VS me es funcional: http://localhost:63694/Login

Localmente con subsitio: http://148.224.108.245/Login

Me resuelve esto: Error HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden
El servidor web está configurado para no mostrar una lista los contenidos de este directorio.

No se ha configurado un documento predeterminado para la dirección URL solicitada y el examen de directorios no está habilitado en el servidor.

A que se deberá... Gracias.

Comment: @marcosbueno: Ese error que te devuelve, ya es un problema de configuración del nuevo sitio Web que has creado (/Login). En mi opinión es un problema de configuración del sitio /Login en tu IIS, y no es relevante para esta pregunta ya que en el IIS de desarrollo de Visual Studio te funciona correctamente.